# how to update UsageLocation of AD User using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, boomi

I am trying to update the UsageLocation of an AD User using powershell so that I could assign an O365 license to it.

Based on [this](https://blogs.perficient.com/2014/11/25/office-365-assign-licensing-user-location-via-active-directory/),

> You can populate “UsageLocation” via the “msExchUsageLocation” attribute in Active Directory

I modified and executed this [code](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/set-custom-ad-attributes-powershell)

```
Get-AdUser -identity "IReyna" | Set-AdUser -replace @{msExchUsageLocation="US"}
```

However it throws an error:

```
Embedded message: can't parse argument number: msExchUsageLocation="US";  
Caused by: For input string: "msExchUsageLocation="US""
```

I am really not sure where to go from here.

UPDATE:
Context of the code is within a Boomi environment (i.e. running Powershell scripts). I just had to escape the braces as they are reserved for arguments (i.e. `{1}`).

`powershell -Command "Get-AdUser -identity \"IReyna\" | Set-AdUser -replace @'{'msExchUsageLocation=\"US\"'}'"`

Comment: That command works fine on my domain. Check your Powershell version and do your AD objects have that attribute available?

Comment: all is working now, thanks for the confirmation as well

Answer (score 1):

The issues are with the double quote use singe quote instead e.g. msExchUsageLocation='US'

Comment: Could you add some documentation or rationale why this would address the error?